# Why am I getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute` in .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

My simplified `.kv` file:

```
<GameWorld>:
    player: the_player

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 5, root.top - 25
            size: self.player.health, 20  # error raised in this line

    Player:
        id: the_player
        center: self.center
```

My simplified Python file:

```
class Player(Widget):
    health = NumericProperty(50)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.health = 100

class GameWorld(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty()
    entities = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameWorld, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.entities.append(self.player)
```

The error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'health'
```

Kivy thinks `self.player` is `None`. Please help me understand what's wrong.

Comment: IIRC new style classes won't let you do references to class members through `self`.  Use `GameWorld.player`.  Or possibly `self.__class__.player`.

Comment: i hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789296/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-health) old post can answer your problem.

Comment: @BrianCain I thought the same thing (and posted an answer to that effect) but testing in a shell indicates that's not correct.

Comment: Is it true that `isinstance(ObjectProperty(), Player)`?  Should you instead initialize `GameWorld.player` as a `Player()`?

Answer (score 1):

When the `canvas` instructions are evaluated, `GameWorld.player` is still `None`, the default for `ObjectProperty`, hence the error.

If you add a test for `None` to the kv rule like this:

```
<GameWorld>:
    player: the_player
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 5, root.top - 25
            size: self.player is not None and self.player.health, 20
```

No error will be thrown, but automatic binding will not be performed. However, if you add [`rebind=True`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) to the declaration of the `ObjectProperty`:

```
class GameWorld(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty(rebind=True)
```

this will work correctly.

---

Leaving less elegant alternate solutions up:

You could instantiate a `Player` object at definition:

```
class GameWorld(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty(Player())
```

Or, you could add another `NumericProperty` to `GameWorld`, with the sole purpose of being bound to `player.health`, but initialized to a sensible value:

```
class GameWorld(Widget):
    _player_health = NumericProperty(1)
```

and

```
<GameWorld>:
    player: the_player
    _player_health: the_player.health

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 5, root.top - 25
            size: self._player_health, 20
```

Comment: I see. Is there a reason why the canvas instructions run before the properties are set? Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @AvivCohn see edit for better way of doing it automatically

Comment: Thanks for the newer solution, it's great. One question though: why does `self.player is not None and self.player.health` work? In a Python shell it evaluates to a boolean. What does it do?

Comment: @AvivCohn [short circuit operators are covered in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)